# Sharing config across multiple separate components

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, bitbucket, config, serverless

I am building a serverless app with aws and have multiple lambda python3 functions. They are isolated out into their separate functions because that is the lambda way to do it. However, sometimes different functions will use the same config variables. For example, the name of a dynamo database table which two components both interact with.

Each of these components are all isolated into separate bitbucket repositories within a bitbucket project.

I can't find any best practices out there to dealing with this. Any ideas on how I could have a central "common config" repo that other repos can point to or a way of automating the updating of all config files within the different repos if I change a variable name? Otherwise I have to go into each individual repo, create a feature branch, commit the changed name and then merge back to master hoping I didn't mess something up along the way. There must be a better way of doing this...?

Comment: Like a git submodule? https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Answer (score 2):

Great question.  [SSM Parameter store](https://hackernoon.com/you-should-use-ssm-parameter-store-over-lambda-env-variables-5197fc6ea45b) is what you are looking for.

To expand on the answer a little the above would be to assume that you are happily locked into AWS which is a fair enough assumption, however, there are alternatives depending on how many shared values you are looking for and of course what the values in the config represent.

Hashicorp has a product called Vault that can be used as a shared data store for secrets.  It even supports dynamic secrets, leasing, and revocation.  Outside of storing secrets, you could choose any configuration management software like Chef, Ansible, Puppet but AWS SSM Parameter will serve your needs.